# Loading nested properties in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is there any way I can avoid using Include and ThenInclude in EF Core ?
I have these models and dtos :

For Book:

```
  public partial class Book
   {
      public Book()
   {
     BookAuthors = new HashSet<BookAuthor>();
     BookCategories = new HashSet<BookCategory>();
     Reviews = new HashSet<Review>();
   }

  public int BookId { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  ...
  public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

  public ICollection<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
  public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
 }

  public class BookDto
 {
   public int BookId { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   ...
   public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
   public IList<AuthorDto> Authors { get; set; }
   public IList<CategoryDto> Categories { get; set; }
   public IList<ReviewDto> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

For Author :

```
public partial class Author
{
    public Author()
    {
        BookAuthors = new HashSet<BookAuthor>();
    }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorDto
{
  public int AuthorId { get; set; }
  public string AuthorName { get; set; }
  ...
  public IList<BookDto> Books { get; set; }
}
```

For Category:

```
 public partial class Category
 {
    public Category()
    {
        BookCategories = new HashSet<BookCategory>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
  }

public class CategoryDto
{
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }
  public string CategoryName { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public IList<BookDto> Books { get; set; }
}
```

And Review :

```
public partial class Review
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public decimal? Rating { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class ReviewDto
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public decimal? Rating { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I have this :

```
public IEnumerable<Book> GetAll()
{
  var books = _context.Book
        .Include(e => e.BookAuthors)
        .ThenInclude(a => a.Author)
        .Include(c => c.BookCategories)
        .ThenInclude(categ => categ.Category)
        .Include(r => r.Reviews)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();
  return books;
}
```

And then in Author :

```
public IEnumerable<Author> GetAll()
{
  var authors = _context.Author
        .Include(e => e.BookAuthors)
        .ThenInclude(b => b.Book)
        .ToList();
  return authors;
}

public Author GetById(int id)
{
  return _context.Author.Include("BookAuthors.Book").SingleOrDefault(x => 
  x.AuthorId == id);
}
```

Between Books and Authors, Books and Categories I have many to many relationship, between Review and Books one to many relationship.
I need this because on the list with books I display the name of the author as well, on an author detail page I display his books and so on. I'm using AutoMapper and DTOs as well.

The same for Categories, Reviews..my json with the returned data becomes very big and it takes a lot of time to load the data into the page, because it has this nested structure. What would be the best solution to do this ?

Comment: *my json with the returned data becomes very big and it takes a lot of time to load the data into the page*, **so it has come to this**.. perhaps what you need is a `ViewModel`, rather than passing the original `Model`, you [map](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) it into another POCO (Plain Old CSharp Object) before serializing into json and pass it into client.

Comment: I'm already using AutoMapper and DTOs :)

Comment: just.. how large is the resulting json? did you paginate it to downsize the number of item sent to client..?

Comment: It has 133 MB and I have only 12 books in the database..this is why I am saying that it's because of the Includes, they create circular references...I didn't paginate the json, how can I do this ?

Comment: If you are using AutoMapper and DTOs, why are you asking about `Include` which is **entity** loading related data concept? Use AutoMapper `ProjectTo` on top of the raw EF Core `IQueryable` and forget about `Include`. Do not use `IEnumerable`.

Comment: And how would this look like for my example ? I have this configured for my Books in AutoMapper :                                   
             CreateMap<Book, BookDto>()
                    .ForMember(dto => dto.Categories, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.BookCategories.Select(y => y.Category).ToList()))
                    .ForMember(dto => dto.Authors, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.BookAuthors.Select(y => y.Author).ToList()))
                    .ForMember(dto => dto.Reviews, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Reviews))
                    .ReverseMap()
                    .PreserveReferences();

Comment: @IvanStoev can you give me an example please ?

Comment: I can't verify the whole thing because I don't have entity models and DTOs, but in case mappings are ok, you would use something like `var books = _context.Book.ProjectTo<BookDto>().ToList();` (requires `using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;`). For more info, see AutoMapper [Queryable Extensions](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) documentation topic.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have updated the question with the models and dtos, thanks a lot !

Comment: @IvanStoev In the Controller I'm doing this : public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
      var books = _bookService.GetAll();
      var bookDtos = _mapper.Map<IList<BookDto>>(books);
      return Ok(bookDtos);
    } isn't it the same thing as using ProjectTo in the Service?

Comment: No, it's not. Read the link from my previous comment, it explains the difference.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but it fails.."'Could not parse expression 'dto.BookCategories.Select(y => y.Category).ToList()': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList' is currently not supported.'"

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do Eager loading. I tried by GroupJoin(expression).SelectMany(...).
This will allow you to load till one level avoiding circular rerefence. I'll show you how I archived it, but with your models.

You have:

```
 var books = _context.Book
    .Include(e => e.BookAuthors)
    .ThenInclude(a => a.Author)
    .Include(c => c.BookCategories)
    .ThenInclude(categ => categ.Category)
    .Include(r => r.Reviews)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
 return books;
```

By the way, you dont put BookAuthors model. So, I'll assume it's structure:

```
var books = _context.Authors
        .GroupJoin(_context.Book,
                    t1 => new { IdAuthor = (Guid)t1.Id }, //where t1 = Authors, you should have IdAuthor in Book.
                    a => new { IdAuthor = (Guid)a.IdAuthor },     //where a = Book
                    (t1, a_join) => new { t1, a_join })
        .SelectMany(t1 => t1.a_join.DefaultIfEmpty(), (t1, a) => new { t1, a }) //.DefaultIfEmpty() = LEFT JOIN
        .Select(x => new AuthorBooksDTO
        {
            IdAutor = t1.t1.Id //please navegate t1 till VS shoows you which model is
            Books = t1.t1.a_join.toList() //navegate t1. a_join will be the list of books.
            ....
        })
        .ToList();
```

For sure, it takes more time to build but performance improve incredibly.
Let us know if it works for you.